# How can I solve approximation evaluation of this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, power-series, taylor-expansion

> > $$\int_{-1}^{0}\sin(e^{x})\,\text{d}x.$$

Approximation of this formula up to difference (error) $1/5000$.

Because of the error size $1/5000$, I think it's solved by Taylor expansion.

Comment: The elementary approach for this problem is to use Taylor series to expand $\sin(e^x)$ as you mentioned

Comment: Another thing: What have you tried so far?  The purpose of asking this is to see what approach you have taken, so we can correct or critique your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following identity according to the [list of Maclaurin series from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions):

$$\sin(x) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n + 1)!}x^{2n + 1} = x - \dfrac{x^3}{3!} + \dfrac{x^5}{5!} - \cdots \quad \text{for all $x$}$$

For your problem, $\sin(e^x)$ can be expressed as

$$\sin(e^x) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n + 1)!}(e^x)^{2n + 1} = e^x - \dfrac{e^{3x}}{3!} + \dfrac{e^{5x}}{5!} - \cdots$$

So

$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{-1}^0 \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n + 1)!} e^{x(2n + 1)}\,dx &= \left.\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n + 1)!} \dfrac{e^{x(2n + 1)}}{2n + 1}\right\vert_{x = -1}^{x = 0}
\end{aligned}$$

Equivalently

$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{-1}^0 \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n + 1)!} e^{x(2n + 1)}\,dx &= \int_{-1}^0 \left(e^x - \dfrac{e^{3x}}{3!} + \dfrac{e^{5x}}{5!} - \cdots\right)\,dx\\
&= \left.\left(e^x - \dfrac{e^{3x}}{3 \cdot 3!} + \dfrac{e^{5x}}{5 \cdot 5!} - \cdots \right)\right\vert_{x = -1}^{x = 0}
\end{aligned}$$

By trials, we see that the number of terms in the expression (after the $x$ value is substituted) is 4 terms in order for the approximation difference to be at most $1/5000$.  Hence, the approximation is around $.59804$

Comment: It is funny to see that we used exactly the same approach but we do not get the same number ! Cheers.

Comment: Interesting.  I should check my calculation carefully.  Let's assume your answer is right. :D

Comment: The antiderivative is the sine integral of Exp(x)

Comment: Wow. How did you compute it? I don't know well where the talyor expansion's difference formula used..

Answer (score 1):

You are correct : use the classical series expansion of Sin(y), replace y by Exp[x] and integrate between the two bounds. The integrals are very easy to compute since they are all of the form Exp[(2n+1)x].

You will see that this is very quickly convergent since :

1 term leads to  0.579331
2 terms lead to  0.580986
3 terms lead to  0.580958

which is the "exact" value to 6 significant digits.

Comment: For information only : In order to compare to the exact value of the integral = Si(1)-Si(1/e) where Si(x) is the Sinus Integral function, a more accurate result is computed = 0.5809583733359800084554724902972285960967663974620997